# How to open native Facebook app and determine the text a user should/could post

Tags: android, ios, facebook, web-applications

I know from [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook) that when I put a `fb://...` link on my website it opens the native Facebook App (on iPhone and even on Android).

But how is it possible to put some parameters to this link? I want to make a share button, with a text/title/image. The user should be able to review it, but when he is lazy he should also be able just to press "Post it".

**EDIT**: My App is an webapp, it is just reachable through the browser (PC or mobile) or through an WebView of a native app (iPhone, WindowsPhone, Android).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native share dialogs with the Facebook SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/07/11/four-reasons-to-upgrade-to-the-new-share-dialog-for-ios/

Here's the iOS documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/

Here's the Android documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/